# How to cut some text from string in bash?

Tags: bash, string

Bash script

I have a string:

tcp      6 0 CLOSE src=111.11.111.111 dst=222.22.222.22 sport=45478 dport=5000 packets=7 bytes=474 src=111.11.111.111 dst=222.22.222.22 s
port=5000 dport=45478 packets=8 bytes=550 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1

I need cut src IP addr 111.11.111.111, 
how?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it:
Pipe it through sed, like this:

```
sed -e 's/.*src=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an external tool for this one.  If you're getting the string from a command output, as seems likely, you want

```
string="$(command)"
string="${string#* src=}"
string="${string%% dst=*}"
```

First line captures all the output.  Second line cuts off the shortest prefix ending in `src=`.  Third line cuts off the longest suffix ending in `dst=`.

Shell globbing is way easier than regexps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk. the snippet below gets all src ip, not just one instance of it.

```
<command> | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/src/){sub("src=","",$i);print $i}}}'
```